# This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""

Tags: python, pyqt

I have come across this error. I have tried everything that the first 3 pages of Google provides. It is driving me crazy. I have uninstalled all my versions of python and anaconda. I reinstalled only anaconda and the error persists.

My Anaconda installation is not in a path that contains any non-ASCII characters

> C:\Users\eee\Anaconda3

I have checked the qt.conf file. All the folders it is pointing to do exist in the stated directories.

After reinstalling Anaconda, everything seemed to work until there was an error and then after that point it went back to the same error. This is extremely frustrating, I just want to be able to use matplotlib in an environment that is more suitable for development than ipython notebook.

I tried PyCharm and also PyDev on Eclipse. The same error shows up in both environments. But not on ipython notebook.

I am aware that you cannot have multiple instances of qt installed. How can I make sure to uninstall all of them such that none are hiding in the shadows.

---

> Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC
>   v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or
>   "license" for more information.

Comment: A guess: try downloading the appropriate wheel from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4) and doing `pip install the_file_name.whl`.

Answer (score 0):

Need to set "QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH" in Environment Variables that points to the "platforms" folder of the active Anaconda Environment (not the Base root environment if you created other environment).  For example, point to ..\Library\plugins\platforms.